# hashcat: clCreateContext(): CL_INVALID_PLATFORM

Tags: hashcat

I'm just trying out `hashcat` v3.6.0 on an up-to-date Arch Linux laptop.

`hashcat -I` shows me this:

```
OpenCL Info:

Platform ID #1
  Vendor  : Intel(R) Corporation
  Name    : Intel(R) OpenCL
  Version : OpenCL 1.2 LINUX

  Device ID #1
    Type           : CPU
    Vendor ID      : 8
    Vendor         : Intel(R) Corporation
    Name           : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz
    Version        : OpenCL 1.2 (Build 25)
    Processor(s)   : 4
    Clock          : 2500
    Memory         : 1966/7867 MB allocatable
    OpenCL Version : OpenCL C 1.2 
    Driver Version : 1.2.0.25
```

I'm invoking `hashcat` on a WPA password hash I recovered from my WAP, using `airodump-ng`. Yes, I know the password, I want to verify that `hashcat` either can or can't find it.

I invoke hashcat like this:

```
/usr/bin/hashcat -a 0 -d 1 -m 2500 -o recovered.hash sporc.hccapx dictionary.txt
```

`hashcat` always ends up giving me this:

```
Initializing device kernels and memory...clCreateContext(): CL_INVALID_PLATFORM
```

What gives? If `hashcat` can't use the platform, why does `hashcat -I` give any information about it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is straight from Intel's OpenCL, and hashcat just passes it along.

Intel's OpenCL has some known issues - so much so that there is usually a warning from hashcat if Intel's OpenCL is being used, which notes that errors can be overridden with `--force`. Did you see anything like that? You may be running into this.

If you are using a stock OS OpenCL of some kind, consider using the latest from Intel.

If you are running under Kali and/or in a VM, consider using hashcat directly on the native platform and/or a non-Kali distro.

Do you get any other errors?

Comment: That was the only message that even hinted at a problem. I'm running hashcat on Arch linux directly on a Dell Latitude 6240, no VM, no container. I'll try the --force option.

Comment: --force didn't help - same meager error message. I'll just take this as a suggestion to try hashcat on a more supported platform and device.

Comment: I had a lot of problems on a Kali vm to configure OpenCL. But Parrot Security Linux has all the needed by default to run CPU hashcat in a vm. It works without touching anything. Maybe as a last resort you can install a vm with Parrot if you finally can't make it work.

Comment: That's fair - though I would also point out that hashcat on a reasonably modern GPU is so much faster than GPU that it's worth trying to arrange for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Try doing `hashcat -I`, and listing how many devices you have. I found that when using `--opencl-device-types 1,2,3 --force`  produced the same issue with this error:

```
clCreateContext(): CL_INVALID_PLATFORM
```

so I didn't use device 1, and it was perfect. I have been cracking hashes since. To be honest, using just the GPU is a much better anyway. I believe it's an error with the Intel GPU driver.